# How could I generate random locations with distances between each other in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, maps

I want to design a function that can generate a 'map' of sorts.

For example:

Location A is created, it is located at some position X

Location B is created, it is located at some position Y, we know the distance between X, Y

Location C is created, we know the distance from C to B, how do we calculate C to A?

Using a triangle method, I suppose I could also assign a random angle and calculate the third side, but what would I do if I added a Location D, E, F randomly?  Would I be calculating multiple triangles that get exponentially worse with every addition?

Comment: Few things need to know. How many locations do you have in the ready-to-pick list? And how many locations do you need to generate in the final list?

Comment: Ideally that would be random too.  Any one over arching 'location container' could have 0 to 50ish sub locations that would need distances between them calculated

Comment: FWIW, I found the problem statement confusing.  Do you know the x/y coords of each location, or only the distances involved?

Comment: The locations will be generated randomly ahead of time and then the distances will need to be calculated between all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you want to generate a list of locations `L[1..n]`, you just randomly pick next location and scan over the `L` to guarantee the distance is over a threshold, otherwise, pick again.

Then, push this into your list `L`. So the total run time of generating a n elements list is O(n^2). When n < 1000, this is fast enough. The following method is guaranteed to terminate, which is designed for a relatively small read-to-pick list, say up to 1,000,000.

```
function generateList(orgList, numberToOutput) {
  if (orgList.length < numberToOutput)
    return false;
  var orgListClone = orgList.slice(0);
  var L = [];
  while (L.length < numberToOutput && orgListClone.length > 0) {
    var n = parseInt(Math.random() * orgListClone.length);
    // Assume we pick n-th element in the list.
    var ok = true;
    for (var j = 0; j < L.length; j++)
      if (distance(orgListClone[n], L[j]) < kThreshold) {
        // n is not an option, swap orgListClone[n] with the last element and pop it out.
        orgListClone[n] = orgListClone[orgListClone.length - 1];
        orgListClone.pop();
        ok = false;
        break;
      }
    if (ok) {
      // All tests passed
      L.push(orgListClone[n]);
      orgListClone[n] = orgListClone[orgListClone.length - 1];
      orgListClone.pop();
    }
  }
  if (L.length == numberToOutput)
    return L;
  // Failed to find the list
  return null;
}
```

Another solution is to calcuate distances between each of the locations ahead, and make a list of too close locations for each location.

So that after each pick, just merge the too close locations to the current set, which takes O(n). And then pick another location which is not included in this set. This method only works when the read-to-pick list is large enough, so that the probability (`1 - |too close list| / |read-to-pick list|`) of choosing a location not included in the set is large. This will take up to O(nm) in total, where m is the average |too close list|.

```
function generateList(orgList, numberToOutput) {
  if (orgList.length < numberToOutput)
    return false;
  var tooCloseSet = {};
  var L = [];
  var lastLengthOfL = 0;
  var repickCount = 0;
  for (L.length < numberToOutput) {
    if (l.length == lastLengthOfL) {
      if (++repickCount > 10)
        return false;
    } else {
      lastLengthOfL = l.length;
      repickCount = 0;
    }
    var n = parseInt(Math.random() * orgList.length);
    if (n in tooCloseSet)
      continue;
    L.push(orgList[n]);
    mergeSet(tooCloseSet, orgList[n].tooCloseList);
  }
  return L;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I will accept yours because of how much effort you put into it, but honestly I don't care how close they are together so long that they aren't at the same location.  Although, in the future maybe I would care I guess.

Comment: If you don't care about the distance, just [shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) the data, which only take O(n) time and this works with most DBs as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this, I haven't tested it, so it's just conceptual at this point.

You could just generate an array of randomly placed points, and each point could hold it's own array of distances, calculated using basic trigonometry.

```
function Point(x, y) {
  return {
    x: x, 
    y:y, 
    addRelative: function(pt) {
       this.realtivePoints[pt] = abs(sqrt(pow((this.x-pt.x),2) + pow((this.y-pt.y),2)));
    },
    relativePoints: {}
};

var randPoints = []; // Lets assume this has a collection of random Point objects

for(var i=0; i<randPoints.length; i++) {
  for(var j=0; j<randPoints.length; j++) {
    randPoint[i].addRelative(randPoints[j]);
  }
}

randPoints[0].relativePoints[randPoints[1]]; // Dist from first to second point.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  This is sort of what I came up with and would like an alternative that wasn't so heavy.  There might not be any other way of doing it, I don't know.

Comment: Cool. Well this could definately be optimised. It's calculating the distance from `A to B` and `B to A`, so you could halve the amount of calculations.

Comment: This assumes you know the x/y location of each point, and is simply pre-calculating all possible distances.  I don't believe that was part of the problem statement.

(Oh, and you don't need the `abs()`, since `sqrt()` won't return a negative value.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it gets geometrically more complicated with each point you add.

The problem is that even if you know the lengths of all three sides of a triangle, you still don't know the orientation.  To illustrate your example:

[image]

You're defining ABC by specifying distances dAB and dBC (which gives you dAC).  But you actually have two possible triangles, ABC and ABC'.  Which means if you add a fourth point, D, by specifying it's distance to one of the points on ABC (e.g. dCD), you've added a 2nd triangle, which can also have one of two orientations, making for a total of four possible solutions.  As you can see, orientation doesn't matter for determining distance between two points on the same triangle, but for determining distances between points on different triangles, it does.

Comment: 'Was going to add more, but looks like you've already chosen the answer.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I was sort of worried about that.  In the end I think I plan on generating this information and storing it in a Dbase now so I no longer have to worry about execution time.

Comment: Are you _sure_ about that???  As noted by others, this is an n-squared problem. 50 points implies something like 1 quadrillion (10^^15) possible solutions for points on opposite sides of your "map".

Comment: broofa, feel free to complete your answer if you have a better solution

Comment: 'Just realized I was making a bad assumption: that we're dealing with right-triangles here.  If that's not the case, then you can ignore pretty much everything I wrote here.  The problem I'm having is it's a little ambiguous what information you have.  E.g. do you know the x/y coord of points C, D, etc?   Or only the distance between C and one of the previous points?  If the latter, than you actually don't have enough information to determine C's location.